# Oracle SQL combine columns from one table

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

i am using oracle sql developer and want to build a trigger to insert values into a table column.

My table is:

```
column1(num) | column2(num) | column3(var)
     1              5
     6              4
     7              3
```

I want to combine the first two columns, so in the end column3 should look like this:

```
column3(var)

       1_5
       6_4
       7_3
```

### My Idea was:

```
create or replace TRIGGER   "Database"."TRIGGER"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON   "Database"."TABLE"
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    SELECT column1  ||  column2
    INTO :NEW.column3

    FROM TRIGGER;
    
END;
```

---

But column3 is still empty, can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: As a side observation - do NOT enclose object names in double-quotes.  This makes the names case sensitive, and you will always and forever have to enclose them in double-quotes, and use the correct case, when referencing them.    And even that aside, I do hope your schema name 'Database', trigger name 'TRIGGER' and table name 'TABLE' are not the names you really use . . .

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a trigger, you can preferably add a virtual column after dropping the existing one such as

```sql
SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN col3;

SQL> ALTER TABLE t
ADD (
     col3 AS (col1||'_'||col2)
    );
```

which always will depend on those two columns, and any DML is not allowed,  already not needed, it's good for displaying purposes with no interfering human factor.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fedd84a6234efb65d8e1124ec6dc58e8)</kbd>

Comment: He will have to drop the existing `col3` first; but this is definitely the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    :NEW.column3 :=column1  ||  column2;

END;
```

Calling a trigger name "Trigger" is a bad idea.